# Oracle forms pre query def_where not working

Tags: oracleforms

I need to set def_where condition where its not working properly.

I am querying for North America in both reg_id_from and reg_id_to, but getting Asia along with North America.

[image]

this is the existing code example :

```
                IF (:FREIGHT_ESTIMATES.DSP_REGION_FROM IS NOT NULL)  THEN 
                                  def_where:=def_where||' reg_id_from in (select id from dss.regions where '||
                                    '                region like '''||:freight_estimates.DSP_region_from || ''''||
                                    ' and            region_type = ''S'')';                             
            ELSIF (:FREIGHT_ESTIMATES.DSP_REGION_TO IS NOT NULL)  THEN 
                                  def_where:=def_where||'  reg_id_to in (select id from dss.regions where '||
                                    '                region like '''||:freight_estimates.DSP_region_to || ''''||
                                    ' and            region_type = ''S'')'; 

            ELSIF (:FREIGHT_ESTIMATES.DSP_REGION_FROM IS NOT NULL)  AND (:FREIGHT_ESTIMATES.DSP_REGION_TO IS NOT NULL) THEN
                                  def_where:=def_where||' reg_id_from in (select id from dss.regions where '||
                                    '                region like '''||:freight_estimates.DSP_region_from || ''''||
                                    ' and            region_type = ''S'') and '||' reg_id_to in (select id from dss.regions where '||
                                    '                region like '''||:freight_estimates.DSP_region_to || ''''||
                                    ' and            region_type = ''S'')';  
            END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

problem is in your IF clause. The first condition is true (region_from is not null), trigger creates def_where for that case and does not check other conditions.

Try this

```
IF (:FREIGHT_ESTIMATES.DSP_REGION_FROM IS NOT NULL)  THEN 
    def_where:=def_where||' reg_id_from in (select id from dss.regions where '||
                                '                region like '''||:freight_estimates.DSP_region_from || ''''||
                                ' and            region_type = ''S'')';
END IF;                             

IF (:FREIGHT_ESTIMATES.DSP_REGION_TO IS NOT NULL)  THEN 
    IF def_where IS NOT NULL THEN
        def_where := def_where || ' and ';
    END IF;
    def_where:=def_where||'  reg_id_to in (select id from dss.regions where '||
                                '                region like '''||:freight_estimates.DSP_region_to || ''''||
                                ' and            region_type = ''S'')'; 
END IF;
```

this should work.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Yes true elsif does not work.

Answer (score 1):

How about switching order of IF conditions so that the 3rd becomes 1st? "..." represent code you currently have, I didn't repeat it.

```
IF :FREIGHT_ESTIMATES.DSP_REGION_FROM    IS NOT NULL AND 
   :FREIGHT_ESTIMATES.DSP_REGION_TO      IS NOT NULL THEN
   ...
ELSIF :FREIGHT_ESTIMATES.DSP_REGION_FROM IS NOT NULL THEN 
   ...
ELSIF :FREIGHT_ESTIMATES.DSP_REGION_TO   IS NOT NULL THEN 
   ...
END IF;
```

[EDIT]

On a second thought, why not even simpler option: declare two variables and set their values at the beginning of the script, using code you already use for FROM and TO options. 
Then concatenate those variables into a single one, deciding only whether to put AND between them (if both of them exist) or not. Something like this:

```
def_where_from := 'reg_id_from in ...';
def_where_to   := 'reg_id_to   in ...';

def_where := case when :dsp_region_from is not null then
                  def_where_from
             end
             || 
             case when :dsp_region_from is not null and
                       :dsp_region_to   is not null then ' and '
             end 
             ||
             case when :dsp_region_to is not null then
                  def_where_to
             end;
```